# bullet raycast vehicle - understanding coordinate system

Tags: bullet-physics

Bullet world space coordinate system is the same as opengl world coordinate system. I have noticed that raycast vehicle has the following function:

```
virtual void btRaycastVehicle::setCoordinateSystem(int rightIndex,
                                                   int upIndex,
                                                   int forwardIndex)
```

How does that function work ?

By default raycast vehicle has the following parametets:

- forward vector: [0, 1, 0]
- forward axis: 1
- right axis: 0
- up axis: 2

Does it mean that y axis is swapped with z axis ?

After calling:

```
raycastVehicle.setCoordinateSystem(0,1,2);
```

I get the following parameters:

- forward vector: [0, 0, 1]
- forward axis: 2
- right axis: 0
- up axis: 1

which makes more sense to me but I'm still confused why a default setup is other (not compatible with world coordinate system) and how to interpret it.

Answer (score -1):

this is Left-hand Rule or Right-hand Rule, that will Affects the direction of the rigid body, you can set value to try.